# JSON Array request cannot be applied error listener

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-volley

I am newbie at Android programming, I have used Google Volley library for calling API and now I have some problem in my Android code. There is JSON error occurred
 [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhtdp.png)

HERE MY CODE :

```
private void loadJson()
    {
        pd.setMessage("Mengambil Data");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();

        JsonArrayRequest reqData = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, ServerAPI.URL_DATA,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        pd.cancel();
                        Log.d("volley","response : " + response.toString());
                        for(int i = 0 ; i < response.length(); i++)
                        {
                            try {
                                JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                ModelData md = new ModelData();
                                md.setNpm(data.getString("npm"));
                                md.setNama(data.getString("nama"));
                                md.setProdi(data.getString("prodi"));
                                md.setFakultas(data.getString("fakultas"));
                                mItems.add(md);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        pd.cancel();
                        Log.d("volley", "error : " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(reqData);
    }
```

Comment: check URL_DATA value exists correct url & reponse holds JSON values.

Comment: Please share screenshot with how you pass data in JSONArrayRequest beacuse it seems like you are passing three arguments only as I see in your screenshot.

Comment: There is some parameter mismatching for the JsonArrayRequest. Check the params you pasing to **new JsonArrayRequest(.......)**

Comment: KulsDroid i've already give screenshoot, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments are wrong in your JsonArrayRequest (you have to pass a String for the URL).
Try something like this :

```
private void loadJson()
{
    pd.setMessage("Mengambil Data");
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();

    JsonArrayRequest reqData = new JsonArrayRequest(ServerAPI.URL_DATA,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    pd.cancel();
                    Log.d("volley","response : " + response.toString());
                    for(int i = 0 ; i < response.length(); i++)
                    {
                        try {
                            JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            ModelData md = new ModelData();
                            md.setNpm(data.getString("npm"));
                            md.setNama(data.getString("nama"));
                            md.setProdi(data.getString("prodi"));
                            md.setFakultas(data.getString("fakultas"));
                            mItems.add(md);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pd.cancel();
                    Log.d("volley", "error : " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(reqData);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have passed wrong parameter in your JSONArryRequest, You need to pass URL (String) and your response listeners.

```
   JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,"http://example.com/feed.json",
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                             //Your code
                       }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to fetch data: " + volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first parameter of `Request.Method.POST` . `JsonArrayRequest` object  takes three parameter in constructor. `URL`, `Listener` , `ErrorListener` .

```
JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're passing wrong arguments to `JsonArrayRequest()`.
According to the documentation found [here](https://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonArrayRequest.html), the method signature is `public JsonArrayRequest(String url, Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener)` and you're passing `(int, String, null, Response.Listener<JSONArray>, Response.ErrorListener)`.

Remove the `Request.Method.POST` and the `null` and you should be good to go.